# Convert pixel position from Google static map to LatLng

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-static-api, mercator

I have a google static map that I have stored in a 2d array. When the user clicks on a pixel I know the row / col [ 0 - 1024 ].

I need to convert that row col back into a lat lng. I have been trying to use the code below to do the conversions from pixel to lat lng and back.

What I have done is to take the center lat lng and the zoom level.

1. Convert the center lat lng to pixel using fromLatLngToPoint.
2. Using the row / col from the image and the width and height of the image get

```java
private static PointF getPointFromRowCol(int row, int col, int width, int  height, PointF center) {

    double adjustedStartCol = center.x - ((double)width / 2);
    double adjustedStartRow = center.y - ((double)height / 2);

    double adjustedCol = adjustedStartCol + col;
    double adjustedRow = adjustedStartRow + row;

    PointF adjustedWorldPoint = new PointF(adjustedCol, adjustedRow);

    return GoogleMapsProjection2.fromPointToLatLng(adjustedWorldPoint, 17);
}
```

The problem is when I put the resulting lat lng back into google maps it is off by 100's of meters.

Any ideas?

```java
public final class GoogleMapsProjection2 {
    private final int TILE_SIZE = 256;
    private PointF _pixelOrigin;
    public double _pixelsPerLonDegree;
    public double _pixelsPerLonRadian;

    public GoogleMapsProjection2() {
        this._pixelOrigin = new PointF(TILE_SIZE / 2.0, TILE_SIZE / 2.0);
        this._pixelsPerLonDegree = TILE_SIZE / 360.0;
        this._pixelsPerLonRadian = TILE_SIZE / (2 * Math.PI);
    }

    double bound(double val, double valMin, double valMax) {
        double res;
        res = Math.max(val, valMin);
        res = Math.min(val, valMax);
        return res;
    }

    double degreesToRadians(double deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    double radiansToDegrees(double rad) {
        return rad / (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    public PointF fromLatLngToPoint(double lat, double lng, int zoom) {
        PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);

        point.x = _pixelOrigin.x + lng * _pixelsPerLonDegree;

        // Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to 89.189. This is
        // about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
        double siny = bound(Math.sin(degreesToRadians(lat)), -0.9999, 0.9999);
        point.y = _pixelOrigin.y + 0.5 * Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) * -_pixelsPerLonRadian;

        int numTiles = 1 << zoom;
        point.x = point.x * numTiles;
        point.y = point.y * numTiles;
        return point;
    }

    public PointF fromPointToLatLng(PointF point, int zoom) {
        int numTiles = 1 << zoom;
        point.x = point.x / numTiles;
        point.y = point.y / numTiles;

        double lng = (point.x - _pixelOrigin.x) / _pixelsPerLonDegree;
        double latRadians = (point.y - _pixelOrigin.y) / -_pixelsPerLonRadian;
        double lat = radiansToDegrees(2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(latRadians)) - Math.PI / 2);
        return new PointF(lat, lng);
    }

    public static PointF fromWorldToPixel(PointF world){
        PointF pixelPoint = new PointF(world.x * (1 << 17), world.y * (1 << 17));
        return pixelPoint;
    }

    public static PointF pixelToWorld(PointF world){
        PointF pixelPoint = new PointF(world.x / (1 << 17), world.y / (1 << 17));
        return pixelPoint;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/) seems to suggest that you can use the other APIs with the static maps.

It seems worth mentioning that you can actually have the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) give you the latitudinal & longitudinal coordinates from pixel coordinates.

While it's a little convoluted in V3 here's an example of how to do it. 
 (NOTE: This is assuming you already have a map and the pixel vertices to be converted to a lat&lng coordinate):

```
let overlay  = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.onAdd = function() {};
overlay.onRemove = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);

let latlngObj = overlay.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(pixelVertex.x, pixelVertex.y);

overlay.setMap(null); //removes the overlay
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this Java function:

```
 function convertPixelToGeo(tx:Number, ty)
{
  $LatBottomSin=min(max(sin($this->mapLatBottom*(M_PI/180)),-0.9999),0.9999);
  $worldMapWidth=(($this->mapWidth/$mapLonDelta)*360)/(2*M_PI);

  $worldMapRadius = $mapWidth / $mapLonDelta * 360/(2*M_PI);     
  $mapOffsetY = ($worldMapRadius/2 *log((1+sin($LatBottomSin))/(1-sin($LatBottomSin))));
  $equatorY = $this->mapHeight + mapOffsetY;   
  $a = ($equatorY-$ty)/$worldMapRadius;

  $lat = 180/Math.PI * (2 * Math.atan(Math.exp($a)) - Math.PI/2);
  $long = $this->mapLonLeft+$tx/$mapWidth*$mapLonDelta;
  return new Point($lat,$long);
 }
```

If it doesn't work try this:

```
    int numTiles = 1 << zoom;
    tx = tx / numTiles;
    ty = ty / numTiles;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like java, also where does this take into consideration the zoom level?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't tried it but I fixed my answer. If its helpful please consider to accept and/or upvote it. Thanks!